# Why jQuery load only when the loading are stopped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add a class `:focus` when I click on a product, so before it loads the next page you can see a blue rectangle.

I have added a jQuery to do it, so when you click a product it changes the class, and add a new class with a box shadow.

But it only works on desktop not on mobile devices.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.product-container').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('aftertap');
  });
});
```

```css
.aftertap {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 3px rgba(113, 129, 194, 1) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 3px rgba(113, 129, 194, 1) !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 3px rgba(113, 129, 194, 1) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container style1 clearfix" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <div class="left-block">

    <div class="product-image-container">

      <a class="product_img_link" href="http://localhost/prestawebserver/forward/102-cropped-leggings-performance-cotton.html" title="Cropped Leggings - Performance Cotton" itemprop="url">
        <img class=" img-responsive" src="http://localhost/prestawebserver/1065-home_default/cropped-leggings-performance-cotton.jpg" alt="cropped-leggings-performance-cotton" title="cropped-leggings-performance-cotton" itemprop="image">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the DOM is already loaded. You scroll to see products, so you click on one, and the Javascript should load.. (the DOM is already loaded)

Only on mobile version. Desktop version it's ok

Comment: or you can place the script at the bottom of the document, before closing the body tag.

Comment: It's working. what are you expecting ?

Comment: Work only on desktop, on mobile i can't see beacuse the page load to speed the next page, and you can't see the Js. How can i do it faster?

Comment: Try [jQuery Mobile](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Instead of `div`'s `click` event, do it on anchor's click event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.product_img_link').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('div.product-container').addClass('aftertap');
  });
});
```

```css
.aftertap {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 3px rgba(113, 129, 194, 1) !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 3px rgba(113, 129, 194, 1) !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 3px rgba(113, 129, 194, 1) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-container" tabindex="1">
  <a class="product_img_link" href="http://localhost/prestawebserver/forward/102-cropped-leggings-performance-cotton.html" title="Cropped Leggings - Performance Cotton" itemprop="url">
    <img class=" img-responsive" src="http://localhost/prestawebserver/1065-home_default/cropped-leggings-performance-cotton.jpg" alt="cropped-leggings-performance-cotton" title="cropped-leggings-performance-cotton" itemprop="image">
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try an hack, simulating a fake delay using setTimeout, before go to next page (you can calibrate delay depending your requirements, in the sample is 800 milliseconds)

```
$('div.product-container').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('aftertap');
    setTimeout(function(){
         $(this).closest('a').click();
      },800);
});
```

[Here a working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/4dweam0w/)